# Nested URL not showing in Django Rest Swagger

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-swagger

I'm trying to document my Django REST API using Django Rest Swagger.

My main url conf looks like this:

```
urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^tickers/', include('tickerapi.urls')),
]
```

and *tickerapi/urls*:

```
schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Ticker API')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^docs/', schema_view),
    url(r'^(?P<channel_name>[-\w]+)/', include([
        url(r'^$', views.ChannelUpdateView.as_view(),name='channel_update'), 
        url(r'^ONAIR$', views.CarouselsOnAirContentList.as_view(),name='carousel_onair_content_list'),      
        url(r'^(?P<carousel_name>[-\w]+)$', views.CarouselUpdateView.as_view(), name='carousel_update'),
    ])),
]
```

As you can see, my url are nested in order to have different views handling the following urls:

- */tickers/{channel_name}* (Operations: PUT, PATCH)
- */tickers/{channel_name}/ONAIR* (Operations: GET)
- */tickers/{channel_name}/{carousel_name}* (Operations: GET, PUT, PATCH)

My issue is that Django Rest Swagger is only displaying part of the nested urls, like so:
[Django Rest Swagger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElWh8.jpg)

From what I can understand Django Rest Swagger is considering that */tickers/{channel_name}* and */tickers/{channel_name}/{carousel_name}* is the same endpoint. Indeed, if I only allow GET operation on the view handling */tickers/{channel_name}/{carousel_name}* (using a ListAPIView), the missing nest URL is showing in Swagger, minus the GET operation: [Django Rest Swagger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWjb1.jpg)

Has anyone come across this issue ? I'm using Django **1.10.5**, Django Rest Framework **3.5.4** and Django Rest Swagger **2.1.1**

Thank you for you help